# ping database successfully, but got error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: asp.net, oracle, connection

I created an asp.net console application.  It runs successfully on my local computer. 
But after I deployed it to the dev server, I got the error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.  I tried to ping the oracle database on the dev server and it was successful.

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: TNS ping or IP ping?  IP ping just tells you that you can access the host machine over the network.  Try tnsping.  You most likely have a tnsnames entry missing on the new machine.  What does your connect string look like?

Comment: Please show your connect string.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the connect details that you are configuring into your application?

When I connect to Oracle from Java, for example, I have to provide a hostname + SID + username (schema) + password. On the other hand, when I connect using SQL Developer or TOAD, I am able to leave off the hostname.

That's because there's a mechanism called "tnsnames" which provides the necessary networking glue to translate a SID into a network endpoint.

Comment: The connection string should be fine since the same connection string works fine on my local computer.  It uses TOAD and uses only SID+username+password.

Comment: You were asked twice to share your connection string - that's the only way anybody can offer any further help with this issue. If you've managed to resolve the problem, could you please share your solution in case someone else comes here looking for help?